# annotations vs annotationEntries in IntelliJ / Kotlin PSI

Tags: kotlin, detekt, intellij-platform-psi

I have a Kotlin annotation:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class Type(
    val type: String
)
```

It can be used on the Kotlin classes:

```
@Type(type = "type")
data class Annotated(
    …
)
```

I am analyzing this source code with [detekt](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt) which provides access to the [Kotlin PSI](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi.html). To get the annotation I use the code like:

```
val annotation = klass
    .annotationEntries
    .find {
        "Type" == it?.shortName?.asString()
    }
```

where, `klass` has a type of `KtClass` from Kotlin PSI. I've noticed, that `KtClass` has two properties: `annotations` and `annotationEntries` and that `annotations` is empty for the annotated class above.

What is the difference between `annotations` and `annotationEntries` and when should I use what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Annotation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ba6da7c40a6cc502508faf6e04fa105b96bc7777/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/psi/KtAnnotation.java) is a declaration (`annotation class`).

[Annotation Entry](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ba6da7c40a6cc502508faf6e04fa105b96bc7777/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/psi/KtAnnotationEntry.java) is an application of annotation (`@`).